# how to display word count while typing text in ck editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

Below is my code which gives the word count on button click,but instead of displaying word count on button click i need to display word count directly when i am typing in ck editor.How can i do this.I am able get the count on button click but i need the same count to be displayed while typing

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
      </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
      <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Get Word Count" />
      <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
}

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string whole_text = CKEditor1.Text;
    string trimmed_text = whole_text.Trim();

    // new line split here
    string[] lines = trimmed_text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

    // don't need this here now...            
    //string[] split_text = trimmed_text.Split(' ');

    int space_count = 0;
    string new_text = "";
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // Modify the inner foreach to do the split on ' ' here
        // instead of split_text
        foreach (string av in line.Split(' '))
        {
            if (av == "")
            {
                space_count++;
            }
            else
            {
                new_text = new_text + av + ",";
            }
        }
    }

    new_text = new_text.TrimEnd(',');

    // use lines here instead of split_text
    lines = new_text.Split(',');
```

Comment: how about this http://w8tcha.github.io/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin/

Comment: Try CKEditor API to get data from it E.g. use ​[getData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData) method (returns HTML) or perhaps using ​[DOMApi](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.text.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need add event handler to CK Editor.
Example from documentation:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
// The "change" event is fired whenever a change is made in the editor.
editor.on( 'change', function( evt ) {
    // getData() returns CKEditor's HTML content.
    console.log( 'Total bytes: ' + evt.editor.getData().length );
});
```

For more info http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

Comment: I don't think CKEditor has Textchange event. It does not handle some properties of ASP.NET TextBox Control.